# How to write a query selecting reasonable trade-offs?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In a table I have two columns obs and abd.  I am interested in finding
low values for both obs and abd, but a low value for abd is more
important than a low value for obs.  In the real world I have a
trade-off between low obs and low abd which is not easy to define
mathematically and would be difficult to explain, but the point is that
what I want to see from the query is some data that would make
reasonable trade-offs.  I would like to know several data pairs within a
range of obs values.  For example:

```
mysql> select obs, abd from flow where obs < 2000 order by abd,obs limit 10;

    +------+--------------+
    | obs  | abd          |
    +------+--------------+
    | 1372 | 0.0000004744 |
    | 1734 | 0.0000017704 |
    | 1010 | 0.0000017716 |
    | 1999 | 0.0000017716 |
    | 1637 | 0.0000036486 |
    |  383 | 0.0000066084 |
    |  745 | 0.0000066084 |
    | 1107 | 0.0000066084 |
    | 1469 | 0.0000066084 |
    | 1831 | 0.0000066084 |
    +------+--------------+
```

From the above results, it can be seen that there are several values
of obs that have the same abd value.  I am interested in only the one
with the lowest obs value for every abd value.  All the other
duplicate abd values should be discarded.  This is easily done by
using a group by clause:

```
mysql> select obs, abd from flow where obs < 2000 group by abd order by abd,obs limit 10;

    +------+--------------+
    | obs  | abd          |
    +------+--------------+
    | 1372 | 0.0000004744 |
    | 1734 | 0.0000017704 |
    | 1010 | 0.0000017716 |
    | 1637 | 0.0000036486 |
    |  383 | 0.0000066084 |
    |  648 | 0.0000066096 |
    | 1540 | 0.0000097586 |
    | 1928 | 0.0000109544 |
    | 1566 | 0.0000119724 |
    |  913 | 0.0000119736 |
    +------+--------------+
```

So far, so good.  Now the problem is that after having seen the first
entry where obs is 1372 and abd is 0.0000004744 I am not interested in
seeing the second entry where both obs and abd are higher.  I am
interested in seeing the third entry where obs is lower but abd is
higher because there is a trade-off between obs and abd.  Again, I am
not interested in seeing the fourth entry because it has values of obs
and abd that are both higher than what is already shown in the third
entry.  The fifth entry is one I am particularly interested in because
although the abd value is somewhat higher, the obs value is far lower.
As for the rest of the entries, I would like to not see them because
they have both higher obs and abd than what has already been seen.

In summary, I would like a query that would show me:

```
+------+--------------+
| obs  | abd          |
+------+--------------+
| 1372 | 0.0000004744 |
| 1010 | 0.0000017716 |
|  383 | 0.0000066084 |
+------+--------------+
```

plus another seven entries where obs continues to decrease and abd
continues to increase.  Is there a way to get the set of data pairs 
with one query without resorting to a procedure?

Answer (score 1):

To get the lowest `obs` by `abd`, here is how you go:

```
select min(obs), abd
from flow
where obs < 2000 
group by abd 
order by abd
```

But it seems to me like the trade-off rule is kind of ad-hoc. You should try to figured out the best rules you can think of and them lay them on the table so that we can achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say you want a [**Pareto front**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_set#Pareto_frontier)

It's not going to be fast but try this:

```
SELECT a.obs
     , a.abd
FROM flow a
  LEFT JOIN flow b
    ON   ( b.obs <= a.obs AND b.abd <  a.abd )
      OR ( b.obs <  a.obs AND b.abd <= a.abd )
WHERE b.obs IS NULL
ORDER BY a.abd
```

Also:

```
SELECT a.obs
     , a.abd
FROM flow a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM flow b
    WHERE ( b.obs <= a.obs AND b.abd <  a.abd )
      OR ( b.obs <  a.obs AND b.abd <= a.abd )
  )
ORDER BY a.abd
```

And this:

```
SELECT a.obs
     , a.abd
FROM flow a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM flow b
    WHERE b.obs <= a.obs
      AND b.abd <  a.abd
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM flow b
    WHERE b.obs < a.obs
      AND b.abd = a.abd
  )
ORDER BY a.abd
```

or this:

```
SELECT a.obs
     , a.abd
FROM flow a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM flow b
    WHERE b.obs <= a.obs
      AND b.abd <= a.abd
      AND (b.obs, b.abd) <> (a.obs, a.abd)
  )
ORDER BY a.abd
```

Check which of the 4 is faster. I would guess the 4th, if you have indexes on `obs` and `abd`. Or better, (as Unreason pointed), two indexes: one on `(obs, abd)` and one on `abd`.

---

UPDATE: 
(small correction on 3rd query).

Comment: or even faster if there is index on (obs, abd)

Comment: also, according to http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ (which is simplistic and different case) left join/is null produces better plans.

Comment: @Unreason: Yes, you are right, an index on (obs, abd) and one on (abd) would probably be best here. For the "left join vs not exists" and which produxes best plan, I'd only trust tests with real data. I think that data distribution may have an effect on large datasets.